# Nokia: Error preverifying class java/langnoclassdeffounderror : java/lang/comparable for java me platform

Tags: mobile, java-me, compiler-errors, nokia, preverify

Getting error preverifying class java/langnoclassdeffounderror : java/lang/comparable for java me platform.

I have migrated my J2SE code to J2ME code. I am aware that some functions J2SE functions don't work on J2ME platform. Therefore, i have already crosschecked for the Comparable class. It is included in Java ME libraries.

Now, i am unable to resolve the errors. Please help me out here.

**Please refer the code below:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import aiproject.CompareToBuilder;
import aiproject.EqualsBuilder;
import aiproject.HashCodeBuilder;
import aiproject.ToStringBuilder;


public class WordProbability implements Comparable, Serializable {


    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;

    private String word = "";
    private String category = ICategorisedCategorizer.DEFAULT_CATEGORY;

    private long matchingCount = UNDEFINED;
    private long nonMatchingCount = UNDEFINED;

    private double probability = ICategorizer.NEUTRAL_PROBABILITY;

    public WordProbability() {
        setMatchingCount(0);
        setNonMatchingCount(0);
    }

    public WordProbability(String w) {
        setWord(w);
        setMatchingCount(0);
        setNonMatchingCount(0);
    }

    public WordProbability(String c, String w) {
        setCategory(c);
        setWord(w);
        setMatchingCount(0);
        setNonMatchingCount(0);
    }

    public WordProbability(String w, double probability) {
        setWord(w);
        setProbability(probability);
    }

    public WordProbability(String w, long matchingCount, long nonMatchingCount) {
        setWord(w);
        setMatchingCount(matchingCount);
        setNonMatchingCount(nonMatchingCount);
    }

    public void setWord(String w) {
        this.word = w;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setProbability(double probability) {
        this.probability = probability;
        this.matchingCount = UNDEFINED;
        this.nonMatchingCount = UNDEFINED;
    }

    public void setMatchingCount(long matchingCount) {
        if (matchingCount < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("matchingCount must be greater than 0");
        }
        this.matchingCount = matchingCount;
        calculateProbability();
    }

    public void setNonMatchingCount(long nonMatchingCount) {
        if (nonMatchingCount < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("nonMatchingCount must be greater than 0");
        }
        this.nonMatchingCount = nonMatchingCount;
        calculateProbability();
    }

    public void registerMatch() {
        if (matchingCount == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Long.MAX_VALUE reached, can't register more matches");
        }
        matchingCount++;
        calculateProbability();
    }

    public void registerNonMatch() {
        if (nonMatchingCount == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Long.MAX_VALUE reached, can't register more matches");
        }
        nonMatchingCount++;
        calculateProbability();
    }

    private void calculateProbability() {
       String method = "calculateProbability() ";
        double result = ICategorizer.NEUTRAL_PROBABILITY;
        if (matchingCount == 0) {
            if (nonMatchingCount == 0) {
                result = ICategorizer.NEUTRAL_PROBABILITY;
            } else {
                result = ICategorizer.LOWER_BOUND;
            }
        } else {
            result = BayesianCategorizer.normaliseSignificance((double) matchingCount / (double) (matchingCount + nonMatchingCount));
        }

        probability = result;
    }

    /**
     * output
     */
    public double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }

    public long getMatchingCount() {

        if (matchingCount == UNDEFINED) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("MatchingCount has not been defined");
        }

        return matchingCount;
    }

    public long getNonMatchingCount() {

        if (nonMatchingCount == UNDEFINED) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("nonMatchingCount has not been defined");
        }

        return nonMatchingCount;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof WordProbability)) {
            return false;
        }
        WordProbability rhs = (WordProbability) o;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(getWord(), rhs.getWord()).append(getCategory(), rhs.getCategory()).isEquals();
    }

    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof WordProbability)) {
            throw new ClassCastException(o.getClass() + " is not a " + this.getClass());
        }
        WordProbability rhs = (WordProbability) o;
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(this.getCategory(), rhs.getCategory()).append(this.getWord(), rhs.getWord()).toComparison();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("word", word).append("category", category).append("probability", probability).append("matchingCount", matchingCount).append("nonMatchingCount", nonMatchingCount).toString();
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).append(word).append(category).toHashCode();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Comparable in the javadocs of JavaME.
So I think it is not there.

Where did you found it?
Maybe some Lib or JSR has included it. Than you need to include this in the project settings.

If you just need the interface, you can define it yourself.